# TableCell doesn't show item.toString() value with custom CellFactory

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, tablecolumn

I installed a custom CellValueFactory and CellFactory on my TableColumn: I'm programming an address book, Salutation is an enum with values "Mr" and "Mrs".

```
salutation.setCellValueFactory(c->new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(c.getValue().getSalutation()));
salutation.setCellFactory((tableColumn)->new TableCell());
```

Unfortunatelly the cells set by my CellFactory don't show anything.
(Note: actually I want to use a custom TableCell, I only used TableCell for testing).
What is the best way to show the item.toString() String on each cell?

Thanks :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: actually I want to use a custom TableCell, I only used TableCell for testing

This is exactly the issue. `TableCell` in contrast to the cell type produced by the default cell factory simply updates the `empty` property of the cell. Removing this initialisation or replacing the assignment of the factory with

```
salutation.setCellFactory(TableColumn.DEFAULT_CELL_FACTORY);
```

would show the result of invoking `toString` on the cell item as would the following `cellFactory`:

```
salutation.setCellFactory((tableColumn)->new TableCell() {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        setText(item == null ? "" : item.toString());
    }

});
```

Note: I recommend not using the raw type but lacking the knowledge about the types involved, I decided to keep using the raw type in the above snippet.

Comment: So is this how the default CellFactory is implemented?

Comment: Pretty much the way I show in the answer, but it also considers the case where the item is a `Node`; in this case it shows the item in the `graphic` property instead. If you take a look at the source code of `TableColumn`, the factory is stored in the `DEFAULT_CELL_FACTORY` field...

Comment: @Lukas have a look at the source files, then you'll know for certain how the default is implemented :)